# How to embed a "Book Now" button to Google search page when someone type my website name in the Google search

Tags: laravel, seo, google-search

This question might be asked before in other ways but I couldn't file my answers. I followed these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62308174/embed-iframes-in-google-search-page), and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596111/how-to-get-grid-view-presence-in-google-search-of-my-website-as-shown-in-google) but I couldn't get.

My website is designed in `Larave` and `Vuejs`.
Currently working on **SEO** optimization.

When you type `Stackoverflow` in Google search the first website comes up is `Stackoverflow.com` and you see a **search box** as bellow screenshot

[image]

I want to show a custom **Book Now** button instead of that search box when a user click the button she should be navigated to a certain page of my website. But I have no Idea how to do this?

If its generated by google automatically, how can I let Google generate such thing for my website.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. Google generates Sitelinks automatically, as stated in [docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/sitelinks):

> At the moment, sitelinks are automated. We're always working to improve our sitelinks algorithms, and we may incorporate site owner input in the future. There are best practices you can follow, however, to improve the quality of your sitelinks.
>
> - Make sure that the text you use as your page titles and in your headings is informative, relevant, and compact.
> - Create a logical site structure that is easy for users to navigate, and make sure you link to your important pages from other relevant pages.
> - Ensure that your internal links' anchor text is concise and relevant to the page they're pointing to.
> - Avoid repetitions in your content.